# Attach swords to mesh/skeleton for exporting as FBX

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

Is it possible to join a separate sword like the one in the picture to a preexisting humanoid mesh. Then have that sword be linked to the wrist bone with a bone in the handle and have the sword be controllable on its own, even though its apart of the humanoid mesh and armature?

Im desperate for an answer on this. Any sort of input would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Make the sword bone a child of the hand bone. `Ctrl-J` will join two meshes into one.

Comment: It doesnt work. I cant figure out a way to have the sword be a part of the character mesh and have a bone be able to control it. Is that even possible in blender? When u originally import TwinBlast from paragon, into blender, you can see the creator was able to do what im attempting with his guns. They were apart of his mesh but separated and controllable on their own.

Comment: It is no different than having a bone move a finger, the mesh of an object can be in separate pieces, the sword verts don't have to be connected to the hand verts, just part of the same mesh. [Here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50002) is a simple example.

Comment: I see what you mean in what you sent me thanks for that. Any chance you can just look at what im working on and tell me if you are able to do it? I would be absolutely ecstatic. Im just not able to get those results on this mesh. for some reason the bone will not properly fuse with the sword. 
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the swords as part of the character mesh, you want to add sword bones that are children of each hand and use them to control the swords.

- In the armature, add a bone for each sword, let's call them sword_l and sword_r. Position them where the sword handles are and have them as children of the hand bones. As children they will follow the hand bone but can be moved separately when desired.
- For each sword, remove the child of constraint, and create a vertex group matching the bone name, sword_l for swordL and sword_r for swordR. In edit mode select all vertices and assign them a weight of 1.0 to the vertex group. This will make the entire sword move with the bone.

[image]

- In object mode select both swords and the character and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them into one mesh. The vertex groups from the swords will also be part of the combined mesh and each sword will now move with the sword bone. As the sword bones are a child of each hand bone, they will follow the hand movements unless you keyframe their location away from the hand.

[This is your model](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50043) with both sword bones.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the reply. Ive asked this question everywhere and not 1 response. And Yeah the way you have it in that file is exactly what I was looking for. One last thing, you said "For each sword, remove the child of constraint", where are you referring to? I don't see an option to remove child of in constraints or modifiers. And when I didnt do that step the sword did not end up moving with the bone.